# Where is the condition "$\gamma$ is limit" used in a proof concerning the relativization of power sets

Tags: solution-verification, set-theory

I was working on an exercise in Kunen's Set Theory (2011):

> **Exercise I.16.6** Work in ZF minus foundation. Let $\mathrm{pow}(x,y)$ be $\forall z(z\in y \leftrightarrow z\subset x)$, asserting that $y$ is the power set of $x$. Let $\gamma$ be a limit ordinal, with $a,b\in R(\gamma)$. Prove that $R(\gamma)\models\mathrm{pow}[a,b]$ iff $b=\mathcal{P}(a)$; that is $R(\gamma)\preccurlyeq_{\mathrm{pow}} V$.

<sup>(The author uses $R(\gamma)$ instead of $V_\gamma$ to denote von Neumann hierarchy)</sup>

*Solution.* ($\Rightarrow$) Suppose $R(\gamma)\models \mathrm{pow}[a,b]$, i.e. $R(\gamma)\models \forall z(z\in b \leftrightarrow z\subset a)$, then for all $c\in R(\gamma)$, $R(\gamma)\models (c\in b \leftrightarrow c\subset a)$. Since $\subset$ is $\Delta_0$, $\subset$ is absolute. So, $c\in b$ iff $c\subset a$. Now, if $d$ is any set, $d\in b$ or $d\subset a$ implies $d\in R(\gamma)$, so $\forall d(d\in b\leftrightarrow d\subset a)$ is valid. This means $b=\mathcal{P}(a)$.

($\Leftarrow$) Suppose $b=\mathcal{P}(a)$, then for all $c$, $c\in b$ iff $c\subset a$, thus $c\in b\leftrightarrow c\subset a$ is true for all $c\in R(\gamma)$. This shows $R(\gamma)\models\mathrm{pow}[a,b]$.   (Q.E.D.)

I have some doubt about this proof because it is not utilizing the condition "$\gamma$ is a limit ordinal". The step "$d\in b$ or $d\subset a$ implies $d\in R(\gamma)$" is concerning $R(\gamma)$, but it seems that the same argument applies to successor $\gamma$ as well.

So, is there something wrong with my proof, or  this condition is really redundant?

Comment: What is $R(\gamma)$?

Comment: In the forward direction, how do you justify $d\subseteq a$ implies $d\in R(\gamma)$?

Comment: @EricWofsey Sets with rank no more than $\gamma$, or by construction $R(0)=\{\varnothing\}$, $R(n+1)=\mathcal P(R(n))$, and union for smaller $R(\cdot)$s in limit steps.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Because $a\in R(\gamma)$, so a subset of it should have rank no more that that.

Comment: @fantasie Yeah, you're right. It doesn't require $\gamma$ to be a limit.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Or was I wrong, there exists an $a\in R(\alpha)$ with some of its subset not in $R(\alpha)$? I am a little bit perplexed here.

Comment: @fantasie No, that's right. If $x\in R(\gamma)$ and $y\subseteq x,$ then $y\in R(\gamma)$... I was momentarily confused before by the separate issue that the power set axiom doesn't hold in $R(\gamma)$ when $\gamma$ is a successor. (Also note, per Eric's comment, that $V_\gamma$ is a much more standard notation.)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Thanks for your comments. (I am aware of $V_\gamma$, but the book uses another notation so I followed that.)